# TensorFlow: no printing output looking up embedding

Tags: tensorflow

I've been following the instructions at https://ireneli.eu/2017/01/17/tensorflow-07-word-embeddings-2-loading-pre-trained-vectors/.

Why do I get no output (in the last cell, which contains sess.run()) running the following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
```

[new cell]

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'glove.6B.50d.txt'
def loadGloVe(filename):
```

[see above link for rest of definition]

[see above link to initialise embedding]

[new cell]

```
sent_toks = None
with open("documents.json") as f:
    training = js.load(f)
    all_parags = [compute this value]

sent_toks = nltk.sent_tokenize(all_parags)
```

[new cell - see above link]

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as le

# init vocab processor
[etc.]
x = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(sent_toks)))
```

[new cell]

```
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocab_size, embedding_dim]),
            trainable=False, name="W")
    embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocab_size, embedding_dim])
    embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)
    foo = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, x[0])

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    print_output = tf.Print(foo, [foo])

    with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        sess.run(print_output)
```

By the way,

```
print(x[0])
```

gives

```
[    0  2827     5  6097    19     0     0    18    13  1427     1 59126
  4135   111     1  7770 43737     2   622     0     2     6 19517 31152
  1245 44144     5     6 20308    10  2891   509   707  6385     4     1
  6307  3649     2    41   970 19123  2656     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0]
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you tell us which version of tensorflow are you using? And how did you run your code (environment, interface/terminal, etc)?

Comment: @Y.Luo I'm using TensorFlow 1.8.0. I'm running the code in a jupyter notebook in a directory whose path includes WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64.

Comment: tf.print, prints on the console, so check the console you have launched your notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented in the note](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print):

> Note: This op prints to the standard error. It is not currently compatible with jupyter notebook (printing to the notebook server's output, not into the notebook).

Have you checked the notebook server's output (console)?